# como transformar um array de arrays em um único array em javascript?

Tags: javascript, array

Dado o array:
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

Como transformer em:
[1,2,3,4,5,6]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Comment: Tenho certeza que é duplicata, mas não achei a pergunta que já existe.

Comment: @hkotsubo Sugiro a você postar isso numa resposta. :)

Comment: @VictorStafusa Acho que a duplicata que o Anderson encontrou já resolve o problema. E a documentação que linkei diz que é um recurso experimental que pode não funcionar bem em todos os browsers, então acho que nem vale a pena uma resposta...

Answer (score 6):

você pode fazer da seguinte forma.:

```js
var matriz = [
  ['A', 'B', 'C'],
  ['D'],
  ['E', 'F'],
  ['G', 'H', 'I', 'J']
]

var array = matriz.reduce((list, sub) => list.concat(sub), [])
console.log(array)
```

Comment: Salvou meu dia fera, valeu

Answer (score 2):

```
var x = [["1", "2", "3"], ["3", "4", "5"]];    
var y = x[0].concat(x[1]);
```